# Detecting if specific signal is applied to circuit

Tags: signal, frequency, comparator

I am doing a project and need to detect if a specific signal in the form of 2 + Asin(2πft) where A is between 1 and 4 and f is 20Hz - 20kHz. Once this id detected I will light an LED.

I was thinking of using op-amp comparators but they can only detect a range of voltages right?

Comment: Right. A comparator can only detect voltage levels.  Best bet is a microprocessor based setup.

Comment: What accuracy do you need on the frequency discrimination? Does 19.995 Hz need to be rejected and 20.001 Hz accepted, for example? Or could 10 Hz be accepted (maybe only if it's a very strong signal)?

Comment: You could possibly use a frequency to voltage converter to generate a voltage proportional to frequency. Your comparators would then be used to check that the signal was within limits. 20 Hz to 20 kHz is quite a wide range.

Comment: @JRE unfortunately it's not possible for me to use a microprocessor in this project.

Comment: @ThePhoton It doesn't need to be really accurate, I can sacrifice accuracy for simplicity to a certain extent

Comment: Hmm. Is that \$2+A\cdot\operatorname{sin}\left(2\pi\: f\: t\right)\$ signal in volts, amps, kilograms, watts per steradian, a unitless ratio against some standard, or what, exactly?

Comment: Supposing that the answer to @jonk is "volts", then consider using two schmitt-trigger logic gates to discriminate the one-volt and four-volt thresholds. The one-volt schmitt gate would output a square wave whose frequency should be easy to determine. Some one-shot chips might have a schmitt input.

Comment: Bandpass filter plus comparator?

Comment: "unfortunately it's not possible for me to use a microprocessor in this project." - why not?

Comment: Without a valid engineering reason you can't use a microcontroller, we can only assume it is a religious restriction.  We are not here to indulge those.  You also mentioned none of this in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, in the case that this is a Circuits 101 assignment, and accuracy isn't that important, and you have to use basic components: maybe do this in three stages, inaccurately, but enough for your assignment. This is kind of a draft, I'm not going to sit down and do the math, sorry:

**First:**

A bandpass filter to filter out all possible frequencies outside of 20Hz-20KHz. Depending on the assignment, I'm not sure what quality of filtering you need. If you need absolute quality, see the other posts.

**Second:**

A simple diode rectifier feeding comparators to detect that it's amplitude is within the proper ranges.

**Third:**

A fat capacitor/inductor LC circuit to extract the DC signal, and a comparator to make sure that it equals two.

**Tie it together:**

The first stage feeds the second, and the second and third stage would be ANDed together to indicate that you're getting all proper results from the stages.

Comment: Ah, you can mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: As a followup question, Is there a certain design to consider for such a large band? (~20k)

Comment: You can use analog device's filter builder.
You can also consider PI filters.
There are also simple IC's that are basically digital filters that you set with a resistor that would work.

Comment: I edited Tie it together to remove an error. If you filter out the DC with a 20hz filter, you can't extract it later, so I changed that part.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to detect a signal by both amplitude and frequency.  You don't give any parameters of accuracy, response time, harmonic distortion, what signals can look like that you need to rejectd, etc, so anything will do.

This is a job for a microcontroller.  The maximum range of your signal is -2 V to + 6 V.  Use resistors to scale that into somewhat less than the microcontroller A/D input range.  In the micro, you need to sample the signal at least at 40 kHz, but faster would be much easier.  Fortunately, that's not hard.

Many of the Microchip dsPIC can, for example, sample a signal with 12 bits resolution at nearly a MHz.  Let's say you sample at 250 kHz for example.  That's one sample ever 4 µs.  At 70 MIPS that's once every 280 instructions, which is much more than it will take.

Keep track of the last positive and negative peak.  Each time you get a new peak, you compare it to the previous saved peak to get the peak to peak amplitude.  Now it's only two compares to decide whether the original signal was within the 1 to 4 Vpp range.

You also find the zero crossings and keep track of the time between them.  Pre-compute the time between zero crossings for your valid frequency range.  Then it's again two compares to decide whether the period is within the range of what you are looking for.

Iff both conditions are met, you set the "detected" output.

This really isn't hard.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an analogue solution then consider a frequency to voltage converter.

[image]

*Figure 1. [LM2917](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm2917-n.pdf) F to V circuit.*

- You'd need to check that the chip could work satisfactorily over such a wide frequency range as you require.
- Feed the output to a pair of comparitors to check that the frequency is within range.
- You also need a precision rectifier circuit to monitor the signal strength. The output of this should be fed to another window comparitor (to check that \$ 1 <= A <= 4 \$.
- The outputs of the two window comparators can then be ANDed to give the required output signal logic.

Comment: I kinda wanted to post the cool analog answer too. But this is a $8 part. Mine would just be a bandpass filter, rectifier and comparator (hopefully a bit less $$ than yours, but not much less) Olin's solution is like $0.50.

Comment: I thought of that but the bandpass filter will have roll-off whereas the F to V can be better defined. You'd also have to handle signal amplitude variation.

Comment: Yes but see OP's replies to my comments up top.

Comment: Correct me if I’m wrong, but you posted voltage-to-frequency (V/F). If think you meant to post frequency-to-voltage (F/V) instead. Figures 18 and 19 might work, but how about just using an LM2917? Might be fewer components; and they’re cheaper too. I’ve used them in a couple of projects myself.

Comment: Thanks, @BlairFonville. You are quite correct. I apparently didn't even read what I posted! I had the LM2917 in mind as I had used it thirty years ago to convert an engine tachometer into a speedometer after I accidentally broke the gearbox speedometer drive gear on my [Triumph Dolomite](https://betterparts.org/triumph/triumph-dolomite.html). The chip featured in many Electronics Today International projects at the time. I used a hall sensor to detect a magnet on the drive shaft and calibrated using a 6 V mains transformer and the drive-train ratio.

Comment: @Transistor Any chance you mean “Electronics Now”? That magazine is where I first learned of the chip. I built a frequency probe from an article in the November 1999 issue (to me some rummaging through my bookshelf just now to dig it out!)

Comment: I think it was Electronics Now until circa 2000, then Poptronics. I think Poptronics went paperless a few years later, and Nuts &Volts took over.

Comment: No, [ETI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronics_Today_International) started in Australia in 1971 and UK in 1972. I'm in Ireland and the delivery of the magazine from UK to my newsagent seemed to vary by weeks each month causing much frustration. Much of what I write here was gleaned from those magazines back in the late 1970s. See the [front covers](https://www.google.ie/search?q=electronics+today+international). It's hard to imagine now waiting for three months to get part four of a project in a magazine.

Comment: Oh, no. I guess you meant what you said. I just googled Electronics Today. Looks like it didn’t make it to the US. Maybe that’s why I hadn’t heard of it. Interesting.